# Mysql Query to retrieve student course curriculum

Tags: mysql, moodle

I need a MySql query to retrieve a specific student course curriculum from the Moodle database, including past and current course enrollments and respective grades achieved. As anyone done that?

Cheers,
HC

Comment: Your question extremely unclear.

Comment: What's the database structure? How do you think somebody can answer this without this information? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Sorry guys my fault I need to search my moodle database, it has the default Moodle database structure. So I need all courses a certain student as enrolled in the past and present and all his grades

Answer (score 0):

In `mdl_enrol` you have the types of enrolments for each course.
Then for each student you can get his list of enrolments in `mdl_user_enrolments`
With this information you can now link a user enrolment to a course ID.

```
SELECT c.id, c.fullname
FROM mdl_course AS c
INNER JOIN mdl_enrol AS e ON c.id = e.courseid
INNER JOIN mdl_user_enrolments AS u ON e.id = u.enrolid WHERE userid = 3
```

Now you can link the course ID to whatever additional data you need to display.
Replace `mdl_` with the prefix you configured when installing moodle. In PHP, replace the prefix with {}
ex: `{user_enrolments} for mdl_user_enrolments`